# Can I Misty Step into Midair?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, flight, teleportation

If I had a flying speed due to being [Aarakocra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/aarakocra) or having [*fly*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fly) cast on me, would I be able to use [*misty step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) to teleport to midair rather than staying on the ground?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Yes, so long as you can see it

The description of *[misty step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step)* (PHB, pg. 260) says:

> Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

So long as you can see the point in the air that you wish to teleport to (and it's no more than 30 feet away from you) you should be able to teleport up to it, and your flight speed from being an Aarakocra or from being affected by *[fly](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fly)* should keep you in midair.

Comment: You don't even need to be able to fly to misty step into mid-air, it's just a good idea

Answer (score 39):

## Anyone can Misty Step into midair.

[Misty step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) just says:

> Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

Nothing in the spell says that space has to be on the ground.

Answer (score 11):

## Yes.  The spell [*Misty Step*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Misty%20Step#content) does what the description states.

As long as the space is within range, unoccupied, and you can see it, it is a valid misty step destination.  Flying does not matter.

> you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

Comment: the grammar in your title is off. What did you intend to say?